# Ubuntu 16.04 poor sound quality + does not autodetect when I plug headphones

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Over my computer I have no front sound, but I managed to enable it by creating the file `~/.config/asound.state`:

```
state.PCH {
    control.1 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Channel Mode'
        value '2ch'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type ENUMERATED
            count 1
            item.0 '2ch'
            item.1 '4ch'
            item.2 '6ch'
        }
    }
    control.2 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Front Playback Volume'
        value.0 64
        value.1 64
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 64'
            dbmin -6400
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 0
            dbvalue.1 0
        }
    }
    control.3 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Front Playback Switch'
        value.0 true
        value.1 true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
    control.4 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Surround Playback Volume'
        value.0 64
        value.1 64
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 64'
            dbmin -6400
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 0
            dbvalue.1 0
        }
    }
    control.5 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Surround Playback Switch'
        value.0 true
        value.1 true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
    control.6 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Center Playback Volume'
        value 64
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 1
            range '0 - 64'
            dbmin -6400
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 0
        }
    }
    control.7 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'LFE Playback Volume'
        value 64
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 1
            range '0 - 64'
            dbmin -6400
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 0
        }
    }
    control.8 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Center Playback Switch'
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.9 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'LFE Playback Switch'
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.10 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Headphone Playback Volume'
        value.0 64
        value.1 64
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 64'
            dbmin -6400
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 0
            dbvalue.1 0
        }
    }
    control.11 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Headphone Playback Switch'
        value.0 true
        value.1 true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
    control.12 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Loopback Mixing'
        value Enabled
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type ENUMERATED
            count 1
            item.0 Disabled
            item.1 Enabled
        }
    }
    control.13 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Front Mic Playback Volume'
        value.0 31
        value.1 31
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 31'
            dbmin -3450
            dbmax 1200
            dbvalue.0 1200
            dbvalue.1 1200
        }
    }
    control.14 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Front Mic Playback Switch'
        value.0 false
        value.1 false
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
    control.15 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Rear Mic Playback Volume'
        value.0 31
        value.1 31
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 31'
            dbmin -3450
            dbmax 1200
            dbvalue.0 1200
            dbvalue.1 1200
        }
    }
    control.16 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Rear Mic Playback Switch'
        value.0 false
        value.1 false
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
    control.17 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Line Playback Volume'
        value.0 31
        value.1 31
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 31'
            dbmin -3450
            dbmax 1200
            dbvalue.0 1200
            dbvalue.1 1200
        }
    }
    control.18 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Line Playback Switch'
        value.0 false
        value.1 false
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
    control.19 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Auto-Mute Mode'
        value Disabled
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type ENUMERATED
            count 1
            item.0 Disabled
            item.1 Enabled
        }
    }
    control.20 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Input Source'
        value 'Rear Mic'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type ENUMERATED
            count 1
            item.0 'Front Mic'
            item.1 'Rear Mic'
            item.2 Line
        }
    }
    control.21 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Input Source'
        index 1
        value 'Front Mic'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type ENUMERATED
            count 1
            item.0 'Front Mic'
            item.1 'Rear Mic'
            item.2 Line
        }
    }
    control.22 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Capture Volume'
        value.0 46
        value.1 46
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 46'
            dbmin -1600
            dbmax 3000
            dbvalue.0 3000
            dbvalue.1 3000
        }
    }
    control.23 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Capture Switch'
        value.0 true
        value.1 true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
    control.24 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Capture Volume'
        index 1
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 46'
            dbmin -1600
            dbmax 3000
            dbvalue.0 -1600
            dbvalue.1 -1600
        }
    }
    control.25 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Capture Switch'
        index 1
        value.0 false
        value.1 false
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 2
        }
    }
    control.26 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Front Mic Boost Volume'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 3'
            dbmin 0
            dbmax 3000
            dbvalue.0 0
            dbvalue.1 0
        }
    }
    control.27 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Rear Mic Boost Volume'
        value.0 1
        value.1 1
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 3'
            dbmin 0
            dbmax 3000
            dbvalue.0 1000
            dbvalue.1 1000
        }
    }
    control.28 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Line Boost Volume'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 3'
            dbmin 0
            dbmax 3000
            dbvalue.0 0
            dbvalue.1 0
        }
    }
    control.29 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.30 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.31 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        value '0400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.32 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        value false
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.33 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Default PCM Playback Switch'
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.34 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Master Playback Volume'
        value 64
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 1
            range '0 - 64'
            dbmin -6400
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 0
        }
    }
    control.35 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Master Playback Switch'
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.36 {
        iface CARD
        name 'Front Mic Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.37 {
        iface CARD
        name 'Rear Mic Jack'
        value true
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.38 {
        iface CARD
        name 'Line Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.39 {
        iface CARD
        name 'Line Out Jack'
        value true
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.40 {
        iface CARD
        name 'Front Headphone Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.41 {
        iface CARD
        name 'SPDIF Phantom Jack'
        value true
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.42 {
        iface PCM
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        comment {
            access read
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.43 {
        iface PCM
        name 'Capture Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        comment {
            access read
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.44 {
        iface PCM
        device 1
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        comment {
            access read
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.45 {
        iface PCM
        device 2
        name 'Capture Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        comment {
            access read
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.46 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'PCM Playback Volume'
        value.0 255
        value.1 255
        comment {
            access 'read write user'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 255'
            tlv '0000000100000008ffffec1400000014'
            dbmin -5100
            dbmax 0
            dbvalue.0 0
            dbvalue.1 0
        }
    }
    control.47 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'Digital Capture Volume'
        value.0 60
        value.1 60
        comment {
            access 'read write user'
            type INTEGER
            count 2
            range '0 - 120'
            tlv '0000000100000008fffff44800000032'
            dbmin -3000
            dbmax 3000
            dbvalue.0 0
            dbvalue.1 0
        }
    }
}
state.NVidia {
    control.1 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.2 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.3 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.4 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        value '0482000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.5 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.6 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name ELD
        value ''
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 0
        }
    }
    control.7 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=7 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.8 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
        index 1
        value '0fff000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.9 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
        index 1
        value '0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.10 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        index 1
        value '0400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.11 {
        iface MIXER
        name 'IEC958 Playback Switch'
        index 1
        value true
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.12 {
        iface PCM
        device 7
        name ELD
        value ''
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 0
        }
    }
    control.13 {
        iface PCM
        device 3
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.14 {
        iface PCM
        device 7
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
}
```

The file has been created by running:

1. `alsamixer`
2. `alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state store`

Then over my `.bashrc` I've put:

```
alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore
```

But these setting even though they provide me a playback on both front panel audio and on back panel audio, the front panel one sound like crap. Even it plays some frequencies when over a video someone talks it somehow the sound quality is low.

My audio interfaces are (provided from `lspci | grep Audio` command):

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `pavucontroll` via `apt`:

```
sudo apt install pavucontroll
```

Then launch it via dash and when it launches select the `Output Devices` (`Συσκευές Σξόδου` in Greek ;) ):
[image: Pavucontrol Laucched]

Then Select where is says `headphones` as you see in the image (My Ui is in Greek and I assume you use `analog stereo duplex`):

[image: Pavucontrol select headphones]

Then select the padlock channel and **MUTE** the `front right` channel. The press the padlock again and you are good to go.

Comment: it helps a lot for answering a question in English if you start the tool with English language, e.g. from terminal: `LANG=C pavucontrol` (also note that you have misspelled the package name)